# Android: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab, gradlew, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build my project on GitLab CI but unfortunately for me I keep getting this error inside the runner:

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

Now I know there is something wrong with my environment but I just cant get my mind wrapped around the problem. I searched on the web and I found I needed to update my `.gitignore` file and I did here it is:

```
### Java ###
*.class

### Android ###
*.apk
*.ap_

### Package files ###
*.war
*.ear
*.aar

### Gradle ###
.gradle
 build
bin/
build/
build.xml
gen/
.gradle/
gradlew
gradlew.bat
gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle-wrapper.properties

### Android Studio ###
.idea
local.properties
.DS_Store
/captures
```

I also eddied my `gradle.build` to contain the following lines:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.0' 
}
```

But again every time I run a build I get stack! Here is also my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
- apt-get --quiet update --yes
- apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip openjdk-7-jdk lib32stdc++6   lib32z1
 - wget --quiet --output-document=gradle.zip https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-bin.zip
 - unzip -q gradle.zip
 - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
 - chmod +x gradlew

 dev:
 script:
 - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

And the line where the error appears is:

```
- wget --quiet --output-document=gradle.zip https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 8):

According to your `gitignor`, CI is never getting the `gradle-wrapper.jar` library, because it wasn't commited yet, but it has to be, since it is used to run the wrapper.

Check, whether is `gradle-wrapper.jar` commited, if no, then just commit it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error by trying to run:

```
./gradlew releaseTarGz
Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

My mistake was I didn't read or follow the directions: I had to run these two commands first to initialize things:

```
gradle
./gradlew jar
```

Then the `./gradlew releaseTarGz` can find that main class as expected.

Answer (score 1):

@Stanislav you were partly right. I managed to figure out the problem and of course as expected it was right in front of my eyes. So as we all know the runner/s on GitLab CI are all "empty". Meaning they don't have anything installed on them. That is why we have the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Now looking back at my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I am telling the runner to get `jdk7` & `gradle` but I am missing the `Android SDK` that is why the error appeared:

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

So my new `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this and it compiles as it should:

```
before_script:
- apt-get --quiet update --yes
- apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip openjdk-7-jdk lib32stdc++6   lib32z1
- wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
- tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk -a -u -t 1,2,3,4,5,6,29,31,32,33,34,45,138,142,145,146,147,148,149,150,151
- wget --quiet --output-document=gradle.zip https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip
- unzip -q gradle.zip
- export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux

build:
script:
- gradle-2.12/bin/gradle assembleDebug
artifacts:
paths:
- app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
```