# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain and no gradle-wrapper.jar exists

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use Android Studio 4.1.1 to build an Android app which works nicely. When I try to run the gradlew script from terminal I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Which means that gradle wrapper cannot find the gradle-wrapper.jar. All solutions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132906/android-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508014/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain) say I should check the .gitignore and add the gradle-wrapper.jar, but since my computer is the main computer where I created the project there is no issue with missing files in git. However, I simply don't have a gradle-wrapper.jar anywhere in the project folder. Nor a gradle binary. So I cannot rebuild the gradle-wrapper.jar what was recommended in other postings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508014/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain). I have a gradle-wrapper.properties thou. Building from Android Studio works fine, so there is no issue with gradle itself.

Any ideas how I can restore the gradle wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a "solution". I just searched for a gradle-wrapper.jar on github and put it into the gradle folder of my project. Now it works. But if anyone has a proper solution I'm happy to know, so I won't accept my answer as the right answer.